# How can I make an amateur demonstration to solve absolute value equations and inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I would like to make a program which can solve absolute value equations and inequalities, but I'm a beginner of using the mathematica. I found amazing good demonstrations at the web-page of mathematica but they are still to complicated to me.

I would like to write a code which can visualize and solve an equations or inequality in this form, `abs(ax+-b)+-abs(cx+-d)=abs(ex+-f)`.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You might want to look at `NumberLinePlot[]`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint I'll look after it in the help section